# Interviewer said to concentrate on personal work and reschedule interview

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

So my interviewer told me a time that conflicts with my schedule so I asked her for a different time on the same day so I can complete some personal work.

She replied back saying no problem we can schedule on a different day but I would like to take it on the day she proposed but at a different time. Is it ok to send this type of email or does it look too pushy to the recruiter?

> Thank you so much for the best wishes!
>
> I also wouldn't mind speaking with you on the day you proposed for Thursday at 2:30PM or before but Friday is completely fine with me as well!
>
> Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not pushy at all; I find it perfectly friendly.

If I were to suggest any edits, I might suggest being a bit more concise (particularly if you are in a STEM field). I might say something like:

> Hi Name,
>
> Thanks for your flexibility, I really appreciate it. I could do Thursday at/before 2:30 EST, or anytime Friday.
>
> Cheers,
>
> Name

Answer (score 2):

I would not send that email.  If you send it you risk her interpreting it against you - that you are dense and don't take social cues.  One of the primary things recruiters are sensitive to is if the person is interested and excited about the job.  If you're moving around interview dates the message is - I'll get to it when I can, I have other priorities and if it's convenient for me we can chat.  Your message should be - this is the most important thing to me, I can't wait to meet in person, and I want the first available slot.  At least, if you want to get hired.

Comment: Hmm I already sent it now we'll see at this point haha

Comment: Well, if you two are able to get schedules worked out, I would make a big deal about the accommodation, and how that makes you want it even more. If  they are easygoing, it is a good sign.  :)

Comment: I think she was being sympathetic towards me since she said "Please concentrate on that. We can move the interview to another date"

Comment: That's pretty nice, and recruiters often are.  Sometimes it's because you are the best candidate, sometimes it's because their job is to move people through.  Never hurts to recognize when people are nice to you, keep in mind the power is in the employer's hands, not the employee.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it less "pushy" offering that even the same day would be ok for you, just at another time if this could make it easier for the interviewer.

But consider that the interviewer has other appointments too, so maybe it's just not possible. Don't sound like your interview is supposed to be the only activity they have to plan. Don't request a new time, just make an offer. If you want to reschedule it again at all.
If you already mentioned this time in your first request I wouldn't ask for it again. Then maybe they already did the best they can.